# array_unique not sorting values from regular expression

Tags: php, arrays, regex, array-unique

So I have the following regex and I count the occurrences of matches like so:

```
preg_match_all("/".$toArray."/i", $input, $matches);

$count_matches = count($matches[0]);
```

However, I want to get only those matches that are unique. And applying `array_unique()` to the following does not seem to work.

```
$count_matches = count(array_unique($matches[0]));
```

Does the key `[0]` mess it up? If so how can I go round this?

Comment: "does not seem to work" --- what does it mean?

Comment: Does not output the unique values.

Comment: Can I do something like this?

`$count_matches = count($matches[0]);`
`$unique = $count_matches - array_unique(count($matches));`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to count an array location

```
$count_matches = count($matches[0]);
```

This tries to count position 0 in the array $matches. Instead of counting how many positions are in the entire array $matches.

Comment: How can I keep the count and in the same get only the unique values?